# How to create a C# session object wrapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis, class-library

How do I create a class library where I can get and set like the IIS `Session` object where I use `var x = objectname("key")` to get the value or `objectname("key") = x` to set the value?

Comment: do you want your object to talk to IIS or are you just making a analogous comparison?

Comment: What specifically is your question? How to add `[xxx]` support to your object? or how to make an object available everywhere? or ... ?

Comment: Acutally, I wanted to write a replacement for IIS Session so I can save the session state for a web farm.  I wanted to write it in a way that I wouldn't have to change all places where the session is currently set or used.

Comment: That is why you should do it via a wrapper class like I posted below.  Apps really shouldn't access the session directly.  A wrapper class will make the access type safe and give you a central point to make all changes so that you can swap out Session for a datastore of your choice if you wish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally I just have a static class that wraps my session data and makes it type safe like:

```
public static class MySessionHelper
{
    public static string CustomItem1
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomItem1"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomItem1"] = value; }
    }

    public static int CustomItem2
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomItem2"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomItem2"] = value; }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Then when I need to get or set an item you would just do the following:

```
// Set
MySessionHelper.CustomItem1 = "Hello";

// Get
string test = MySessionHelper.CustomItem1;
```

Is this what you were looking for?

**EDIT:** As per my comment on your question, you shouldn't access the session directly from pages within your application. A wrapper class will make not only make the access type safe but will also give you a central point to make all changes.  With your application using the wrapper, you can easily swap out Session for a datastore of your choice at any point without making changes to every single page that uses the session.

Another thing I like about using a wrapper class is that it documents all the data that is stored in the session. The next programmer that comes along can see everything that is stored in the session just by looking at the wrapper class so you have less chance of storing the same data multiple times or refetching data that is already cached in the session.

Comment: Like the static class better.  It makes access easier.

Comment: +1 Good pattern. Should always be used to access session data.

Comment: Nice pattern. Only critique is prepending the class name with "My" is unnecessary noise.

Comment: Making a session helper that is static is such a pain. It makes unit testing very very hard when that static class is sprinkled all over the controllers.

We have a saying for unnecessary static stuff. "This is why we can't have nice thing."

Answer (score 5):

I guess, you could use a generic dictionary like `Dictionary<string, Object>` or something similar to achieve this effect. You would have to write some wrapper code to add an Object when accessing a non-existend item by for example a custom default property in your Wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some thing like this

```
public class Session
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _instance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private Session()
    {            
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Instance
    {
        get
        {
           if(_instance == null)
           {
               _instance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
           }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
Session.Instance["key"] = "Hello World";
```

Comment: I apologize for commenting on an old answer, but since this dictionary is in a static object, is there any possibility that it would be shared with other users of a web app?  Say, if this object held the username, for instance, would that be a problem?