# Variable wrapper for session-persistance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session-variables

i am pretty sure i saw nice thing some time ago (maybe in Enterprise library, not sure), but i just cant google it now - generic variable wrapper for making it persistent by storing it in session. Usage like this:

`Persistent< string >  Name {get;set;}`

// reguest 1.

Name = "A"; // in fact storing to session.. maybe Name.Value = "A" is necessary, not sure if implicit cast can be done here

// reguest 2.

return Name; // returns string "A", implicit conversion

of course, I would implement it myself already before asking, but i cant think of any good (consistent and fast) way to determine session keys for variables (how to make sure, I will get the same for the Name every time, but different for Age, you know..)

Thanx,
Roman

Comment: You're just trying to make a session wrapper object, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to make a custom session wrapper, I would suggest using an expression to make sure your magic strings don't get outdated.

```
 public int SomeProperty
 {
     get { return GetValueFor(x => x.SomeProperty); }
     set { SetValueFor(x => x.SomeProperty, value); }
 }

 protected T GetValueFor<T>(Expression<Func<ThisClass, T>> propertySelector)
 {
     string propertyName = // Get Value from expression.. to loo long to post here

     return (T)_session[propertyName];
 }

 protected SetValueFor<T>(Expression<Func<ThisClass, T>> propertySelector, object value)
 {
     string propertyName = // Get value from expression

     _session[propertyName] = value;
 }
```

This way, all your properties are just mapped on the session object in a strongly typed way, and if you ever refactor, you dont have to worry about magic strings.

Comment: And don't forget to make sure that the session key includes something to disambiguate `ThisClassInstance1.SomeProperty`, `ThatClassInstance1.SomeProperty`, `ThatClassInstance2.SomeProperty`, `ThisClassInstanceN.SomeProperty` etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
private int CustomerID
{
    get
    {
        if( Session["CustomerID"] != null )
            return Convert.ToInt32( Session["CustomerID"] );
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set { Session["CustomerID"] = value; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

An alternative might be something like this:

```
public class Persist<T>
{
    private string ObjectName;

    public Persist( string Name )
    {
        ObjectName = Name;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        return (T)(HttpContext.Current.Session[ObjectName]); 
    }

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[ObjectName] = value;
    }
}
```

This is shown wrapped into a simple Singleton class.

```
public class SV
{
    private static readonly SV instance = new SV( );

    public Persist<DateTime> FiscalDate;
    public Persist<decimal> Revenue;

    private SV( )
    {
        FiscalDate = new Persist<DateTime>( "FiscalDate" );
        Revenue = new Persist<decimal>( "Revenue" );
    }

   public static SV Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         return instance; 
      }
   }
}
```

Usage is a bit wordy, unfortunately.

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if( !Page.IsPostBack )
    {
        SV.Instance.Revenue.Set( 1234567890M );
        SV.Instance.FiscalDate.Set( new DateTime( 2011, 3, 15 ) );
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    DateTime when = SV.Instance.FiscalDate.Get( );
    decimal amount = SV.Instance.Revenue.Get( );
}
```

Comment: yes, of course, this is trivial solution which i want to encapsulate, because i will have many of variables with this behaviour, and I like things DRY

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jim31415 and I wrapper my session like followings,

```
internal class SessionHelper {
    private void Set<T>(string key, T value) {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }
    private T Get<T>(string key) {
        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    public int MemberID {
        get { return Get<int>("SK_MemberID"); }
        set { Set<int>("SK_MemberID", value); }
    }
    public string MemberAccount {
        get { return Get<string>("SK_MemberAccount"); }
        set { Set<string>("SK_MemberAccount", value); }
    }
    public string MemberDisplayName {
        get { return Get<string>("SK_MemberDisplayName"); }
        set { Set<string>("SK_MemberDisplayName", value); }
    }
    public string MemberGuid {
        get { return Get<string>("SK_MemberGuid"); }
        set { Set<string>("SK_MemberGuid", value); }
    }
}
```

With [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322008/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-session-object-wrapper), the helper class can be declared with `static` keyword.

Comment: Good approach! Eliminates error-prone casting. But i would suggest to inject HttpContextBase  to be able to test controller or service if use SessionWrapper inside one

Comment: Maybe it can be implemented by overwrite `Set<T>()` and `Get<T>()` functions, in order to provide a `SessionWrapper` for testing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess one way you could do it is:

```
public class Persistent<T>
{
    private readonly string _sessionKey;
    private static readonly bool _valueType;

    static Persistent()
    {
        _valueType = typeof(T).IsValueType;
    }

    public Persistent(T value = default(T))
    {
        _sessionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        SetValue(value);
    }

    private void SetValue(T value)
    {
        var item = (_valueType)
          ? new PersistentWrapper { Value = value }
          : (object)value;

        HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionKey] = item;
    }

    private T GetValue()
    {
        object item = HttpContext.Current.Session[_sessionKey];
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (_valueType) return ((PersistentWrapper)item).Value;

            return (T)item;
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class PersistentWrapper
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Persistent<T> value)
    {
        if (value == null) return default(T);
        return value.GetValue();
    }

    public static implicit operator Persistent<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Persistent<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Which could be used as:

```
public class Person
{
    public Persistent<string> Name { get; set; }
    public Persistent<int> Age { get; set; }
}
```

With usage:

```
var person = new Person();
person.Name = "Matt";
person.Age = 27;
```

Although it just feels dirty to me...

Comment: this solution is wrong - guid will be different each time the instance is created - for each request.. so you cant retrieve the value stored in previous request processing;